# Split text data by semi-colons

Tags: marketing-cloud

In extacttarget we have an extension  x. The data in that extension is imported from Salesforce. X has a field named `city__C`, which corresponds to a picklist field in Salesforce, so values in that list are separated by semi-colons. I need to split the fields in exacttarget using a query.

For example,

> london;paris;hongkong;mumbai;new york;york

should be split into

> london
>   paris
>   hongkong
>   mumbai
>   new york
>   york

I can’t use any SQL string functions to split the text. Even the LIKE operator doesn’t work.

Comment: i think this is multiselect picklist field try include exclude function, here is the link to understand in detail http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_multiselect_picklists.htm

Comment: Do you mean when querying or when using the data?

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use the `split()` function as follows

```
String[] regions = myObj.Region__C.split(';');
```

This will return the values in the format you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

To query a multi-picklist using SOQL, you have to use the following in your case:

`SELECT Id FROM MyObject__c WHERE city__C INCLUDES ('london')`

Answer (score -1):

used ascii value of semicolon

like char(59)+'Some Text'